# Initialize immutable global variable with a function in Rust

Tags: rust, global-variables, global

I need to have a lot of data stored as an immutable variable that can be accessed by every function.

The optimal way would be to use a `const DATA: [u64; 1000] = [ 1, 110101, ... ]` and that is possible because I know how this data looks like. Due to the huge amount of data that needs to be created, the only practical way is to initialize the constant with a function. That does not currently work in Rust, and it maybe will never, because I need to run loops in the initializer function which  isn't even supported in the nightly build.

It should be possible to initialize the data in the `main` function as ordinary `let DATA: [u64; 1000] = ini_fn();`. Then I would need to give all subfunctions a reference to this data. That's kinda inconvenient; if a function `foo3()` were to need the `DATA` but gets called by `foo2()` which gets called by `foo1()` which gets called by main(), I would need to borrow the `DATA` three times and really using it just once.

I am searching a more reasonable solution for this problem / some equivalent to this C code:

```c
std::array<int, 64>  ini_data()
{
  std::array<int, 64> ret;
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  {
    ret[i] = i;
  }
  return ret;
}

const std::array<int, 64> DATA = ini_data();

void main()
{
  print(DATA);
}
```

It would be better to have this data on the stack because speed is important, but I hope that the data gets cached so this is not a priority.

Comment: Just remove the "mutable" part of the linked duplicates: `lazy_static! { static ref DATA: Vec<u8> = create_data_fn(); }`.

Comment: FWIW, I think that actually creating the value in `main` and passing down references is a very reasonable solution. Rust's lifetimes prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot and you can optionally avoid all multithreaded synchronization issues.

Comment: Actually, i have maybe 10 different arrays that are like the `DATA`-array. Isn't this a performance issue if I call these function (`foo()1, foo()2, foo()3`) very often because I always have to copy the reference-pointer?

Comment: You could also generate the constant by running a function in a build script and then importing the generated code (the 3rd duplicate I added).

Comment: Accessing the `DATA` variables requires an atomic variable check (to ensure that they have been initialized) and then you get a reference to (in this case) the `Vec` which can be dereferenced to get to the data. I don't believe either of those are really that much overhead, but you can "cache" that by doing something like `let data = &**DATA`, which will set `data` to an `&[u8]` and then pass that down to the pieces you need.